# Merge [rest] into [rest-api]

Tags: discussion, tags

- [rest-api](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest-api): 1,078 tagged questions

  > Magento REST API defines a set of functions that a developer can use to perform requests and receive responses. These interactions are performed using the HTTP protocol.
- [rest](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest): 813 tagged questions

  > Denotes questions related to the REST API on Magento

These tags are both about the Magento REST API. I think they should be merged and [rest](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest) should be a synonym of [rest-api](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!. Thanks for the suggestion